# Confidence intervals vs law of the iterated logarithm

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem, confidence-interval

Let $X_i$ be iid random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$. Let $S_n=\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ denote the sample mean. By CLT it is well known that $(S_n - \frac{1.96}{\sqrt n}, S_n + \frac{1.96}{\sqrt n})$ is an asymptotic $95\%$ confidence interval for $\mu$.

By the law of the iterated logarithm, $\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt {\log \log n} }(S_n-\mu)$ has $\limsup$ equal to $\sqrt 2$ almost surely. Thus for almost all $w$, we have $\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt {\log \log n} }(S_n-\mu) \approx \sqrt 2$ infinitely often, thus $ S_n \approx \mu +\frac{\sqrt {2 \log \log n}}{\sqrt n }$ infinitely often.

For large $n$, $\sqrt {2 \log \log n}$ is much bigger than $1.96$, which seems to contradict the confidence interval. Can someone shed light on this  paradox (if there is any) ?

Comment: What do you mean by $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\log \log n}}(S_n-\mu)\approx \sqrt{2}$$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots $ iid with $X_1\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then 
$$ W_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\log \log n}}S_n \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{1}{2\log \log n}\right).$$
Note $$W_n \to 0$$ in law, but $$ W_n\nrightarrow $$ in the sense a.s. convergence. Indeed, by the law of iterated logarithm
$$ \liminf W_n =-1,\quad \limsup W_n =1$$
with probability one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I think this problem perfectly encapsulates misunderstandings with the CLT which I have been thinking about a lot.

The CLT says that $\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \mu\right)$ converges to $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ **in distribution**. This is key, because it actually says nothing about the convergence of $\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \mu\right)$ for any given sample, i.e. any given series of measurements of the $X_i$, as $n\to \infty$. In fact, you can see from the LIL that, seen as a statistic of a sample of size $n \to \infty$ (i.e. a test where keep collecting more data), $\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \mu\right)$ **diverges with probability 1!** This is in stark contrast from the (Strong) Law of Large Numbers, which says that $S_n$ converges to $\mu$ with probability $1$.

The way to think about the convergence in distribution in the CLT is that, the larger $n$ gets, the more that the distribution of the **random variable** $\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \mu\right)$ looks normal. In other words, if you fix some large $n$, and perform a bunch of different tests where, in each, you collect a sample of size $n$ and then calculate $\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \mu\right)$, then all of these different calculations will be distributed approximately like $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, and that approximation will get better the bigger you make $n$.

Again, a core difference between the CLT and the LIL and LLN are that the latter two give **almost sure** convergence, whereas the former is only convergence in distribution. But where analysis trains us to think about this as just being a weaker statement, it actually means that we have a fairly different interpretation. Namely, **the LIL and LLN can tell you what happens with their respective statistics as you collect more and more data for a given sample,** and thus enable you to say things about the distribution of these statistics viewed as random variables for fixed large sample sizes. For example, since we know that $S_n$ will converge to $\mu$ as the sample grows, with probability $1$, we know that in fact the random variables $S_n$ converge to the constant function $\mu$. The full statement of the LLI tells you that its statistic doesn't converge anywhere almost surely, although it converges in probability to $0$ (the [Wikipedia discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm#Discussion) is worth viewing here).

On the other hand, the CLT doesn't tell you anything about $\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \mu\right)$ as a **statistic of a sample going to infinity**, which is good because LIL says that it doesn't converge. However, it tells us how to consider the distribution of this **as a random variable for a fixed sample size $n$,** but with the knowledge that its statement is an approximation that is more accurate the larger $n$ is.